# Can I disable password login but still allow sudo?

Tags: ssh, sudo, password

While answering comments I realized what I should really be asking, so I asked [a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757292/disable-password-login-but-keep-sudo-v).

---

I'm on a Raspberry Pi, but I don't think this question is specific to Raspberry Pi OS.

I only use an SSH key to log in as user `pi`.

If, as user `pi`, I want to use sudo, I need to enter the password for user `pi`. So I'd like to set this password to something simple, like `pi`.

But of course I don't want to expose a user account via SSH with such a simple password, so I'd like to disable the ability to log in with this password.

Is that possible?

Comment: If you set it to something so guessable, why not simply set sudo to not require a password for that user at all?

Comment: @MarcusMüller That would be the best solution. I even have a file (by default on Raspberry Pi OS) in `/etc/sudoers.d` that contains `pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` . Yet, when [a shell script runs](https://github.com/dw-0/kiauh/blob/master/scripts/ui/update_menu.sh#L44) `sudo -v` it still asks for a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling password authentication is a feature of all ssh servers I've worked with! So, yeah, that's possible. If you're running openssh, /etc contains sshd_config, which probably is well documented and already contains the appropriate configuration line, commented out.

Comment: I was thinking more of disabling password authentication *for that user*, but yeah, disabling it completely is indeed a viable solution.

Comment: @AndreKR you can disable password authentication for a specific user or group, using `Match User username` in `sshd_config`

Comment: @AndreKR frankly, if your device is "attached to the internet" with its SSH server, disabling password authentication is practically always the first thing you do. I've seen people do *exceptions* for specific "hard to guess" user names. It really helps with the endless port scans and default login attempts if your SSH server simply says "nope, you want to try a password? goodbye.".