# Disable password login but keep sudo -v?

Tags: ssh, sudo, password

I'm on a Raspberry Pi, but I don't think this question is specific to Raspberry Pi OS.

I only use an SSH key to log in as user pi.

I have [a script](https://github.com/dw-0/kiauh) that calls `sudo -v` which currently asks for the password for user `pi`.

I want to make this step easy, so preferably have it not ask for a password at all or have a very simple password (like `"pi"`).

But of course I don't want to expose a user account via SSH with such a simple password.

I already have a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` that contains `pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` but it doesn't disable the password question for `sudo -v`.

What are my options?

---

Edit: Output of `sudo -l` as requested in the comments:

```
pi@klipper:~ $ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for pi on klipper:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin, env_keep+=NO_AT_BRIDGE, env_keep+="http_proxy HTTP_PROXY", env_keep+="https_proxy HTTPS_PROXY", env_keep+="ftp_proxy FTP_PROXY",
    env_keep+=RSYNC_PROXY, env_keep+="no_proxy NO_PROXY"

User pi may run the following commands on klipper:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Do you allow logging in over ssh with a password? Since you're using a key (as you should) why not disable logging in with a password entirely? Wouldn't that then let you set as simple a password as you want without changing the overall security level?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why this question is materially different from [the one you asked earlier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/757263/100397)

Comment: @roaima In the previous question I assumed there is simply no way to allow `sudo -v` without password, and then everyone answered/commented "just tell sudo to not ask for a password". So now I'm asking how to do that, because that would of course be the best way.

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l` when run as the `pi` user to the question, please

Comment: @muru I added the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove (or better, comment out) the first of the two lifted authorisation lines in `sudoers` that applies to `pi`:

> ```
> (ALL : ALL) ALL
> (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
> ```

This unwanted one does not have the `NOPASSWD` flag so you will be prompted for a password. (First matching rule applies.)

Generally speaking, I would advise you open two shells. Use `sudo -s` in the first to get a root shell and do not close this until you have confirmed that your edits haven't locked you out from using `sudo`. Use the second for your testing. Always use `visudo` to edit the `sudoers` files.

---

I should point out that if the first line corresponds to the group definition

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

you should not comment that out without good reason as it allows anyone who is a member of the `sudo` group to use the `sudo` command.

Either modify it so that all members of this group need not provide their password, or else put your own user line above it so that it matches first:

```
pi ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Yesss, this worked. It came from a line in `/etc/sudoers` that read `%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`. I commented that line and now the script can run sudo commands without asking for a password.